# Why mysql_config add -fPIC?

Tags: mysql, c, gcc, compiler-flags

When I run `mysql_config --cflags`, the output is:

```
-I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing
```

I know what -fPIC do, but I can't understand why mysql_config is outputing this flag, since it could be a static library or an executable, and anyone building a dynamic library most likely would already have that flag. My thoughts are it's either a bug, or libmysql is doing something really weird to require that.

Is there anything that could require -fPIC in an executable or it is just a bug?

Comment: I'd recommend Postgres over mySQL.  In mySQL, a query once issued cannot be cancelled, which is a fundamental design flaw.

Comment: With version 5.1.63 I dont see it. Output is `$ mysql_config --cflags` ->
`-I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing   -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX`. It appears that `mysql_config` is just a shell script... open up & see if you can make any sense why it is added

Comment: @another.anon.coward I checked the file and it does not comment why, it just add that flag. The version I have is 5.0.83.

Comment: Maybe it is hidden in one of the `changelog`s between versions as it seems to have been removed in the newer version, but unfortunately not able to get any kind of `changelog` between versions of mysql